# unpickling json into a case class with option

Tags: scala.js, play-json, upickle

Consider this case class:

```
case class Sample(status: String, message: Option[String])
```

`Sample(status="OK")` is serialized by play-json to JSON as

```
{
   "status":"OK"
}
```

and `Sample(status="OK", message=Some("message content"))`

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "message":"message content"
}
```

This is how optional fields behave in Play and elsewhere in the JS world and typescript. For example I can easily cast the above json into an interface like this in Typescript:

```
interface Sample {
    status: string;
    message?: string;
}

const sample: Sample = { status: "OK" } as Sample;
```

Now I understand that there are a number of pickling concepts that serialize/deserialize in a consistent manner. However it's interesting that no pickling library supports this kind of deserialization into case class with ease. Maybe I am missing something.. Any recommendations?

UPDATE -- this is the behavior i would like to observe

json:

```
{ "status": "OK" }
```

becomes:

```
Sample("OK",None)
```

json:

```
{ "status": "OK", "message": "message content" }
```

becomes:

```
Sample("OK",Some("message content"))
```

Yes, indeed the following code can achieve this. But I don't want to explicitly specify this kind of distinction at many different places.

```
import upickle.default.Reader

case class Sample(status: String, message: Option[String])

implicit def r: Reader[Sample] = Reader[Sample] {
  case (x:upickle.Js.Value) =>
    Sample (
      status   = x.obj.get("status").get.toString(),
      message  = x.obj.get("message").flatMap(x => Some(x.toString))
    )
}

upickle.default.readJs[Sample](upickle.json.read(jsonText))
```

Comment: ```implicit def optionDecoder[T](implicit option:Decoder[Option[T]]):Decoder[Option[T]] = {
  option
}
```

Comment: there is a upickle pr to fix this: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/upickle/issues/528